# Tom Riddle in the Tri-Wizard tournament

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort

Is there a canon statement or quote from J.K. Rowling that says that Voldemort won or was a champion in the Tri-Wizard tournament when he was in Hogwarts? If there is why didn't J.K. Rowling mention that about Tom Riddle's time in Hogwarts like she mentioned he was a prefect and the head boy? If not why didn't he join the tournament?

Comment: Not wondering about this is normal, because from reading the books you know it's impossible. It's like asking if Voldemort went to America when Europe "discovered" it.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

It is not possible at all that Voldemort would have taken part in that tournament as it was not held for over 200 years (since 1792 to be exact). I have no english version of the books on hand, but on [Pottermore](https://www.pottermore.com/features/triwizard-tournament-retrospective) you can read the following text:

> after some, err, accidents, (all three champions were injured in 1792) the contest petered out. That was until its revival two centuries later in 1994, when extra safety precautions were added by the organisers.

Comment: This answer doesn't tally with Dumbledore's assertion that there were attempts to revive it **after 1792**, albeit with limited success.

Comment: My opinion is, that the "attempts" where not sucessfull, I interpret that as: No tournament took place, it was only the attempt to start one...

Comment: Or a tournament was started, but due to an unfortunate death also quickly cancelled.

Answer (score 47):

Per Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire.

> *‘As I was saying,’ he said, smiling at the sea of students before him,
> all of whom were still gazing transfixed at Mad-Eye Moody, ‘we are to
> have the honour of hosting a very exciting event over the coming
> months, **an event which has not been held for over a century.** It is my
> very great pleasure to inform you that the Triwizard Tournament will
> be taking place at Hogwarts this year.’*
>
> <sub><sup>HP:GoF - Chapter 12: The Triwizard Cup</sup></sub>

Since Voldemort is only in his 70s at the point at which he dies (indicating that he was likely born in the late 1920s) and the last Triwizard cup was held some time before the late 1800s, Voldemort can't possibly have taken part<sup>*</sup> in a Triwizard cup since **the last one was held at least 50 years before he was at Hogwarts.**

<sub><sup>*Unless he used a time-turner, obvs</sup></sub>

---

It has since been revealed on Pottermore that [the Tournament was formally cancelled in the 1790's](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/147039/20774) however, Dumbledore does note that there have been attempts at revivals since that point.

> *‘There have been several attempts over the centuries to reinstate the
> Tournament,’ Dumbledore continued, ‘none of which have been very
> successful.*

Comment: If the attempts have not been successful, for me that means: There was no tournament, not that there had been one and that it failed...but that probably is just my interpretation...

Comment: @TorstenLink - Not "not successful", just not "very successful". That implies some element of success, if not a revival.

Comment: @Valorum, In my opinion it reads to say that the attempts were not very successful, if an attempt at reinstating something is "not very successful" I'd find it safe to assume that the tournament hadn't happened, however there had been steps taken towards attempting to host a tournament.

Comment: @Edlothiad - Since the tourney is supposed to be hosted at all three schools, consecutively, perhaps he means that it only ended up being hosted at one or two before being cancelled again.

Comment: "Not very successful" can be an understated way of saying "not successful". The attempts to reinstate the tournament were not very successful, i.e. they did not gain enough traction to succeed (even if they had some key supporters).

Answer (score 11):

According to [Pottermore](https://www.pottermore.com/features/triwizard-tournament-retrospective), the Triwizard Tournament was discontinued mid-18th century and only resumed during Harry's 4th year. Thus, Tom Riddle couldn't have participated in it.